# Conditional Landing Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

My goal is to direct the user to a thank you page based on the their drop down selection.

This code properly directs the user to "thank-you" if YPN or Y13 are selected and directs the user to "guide-thank-you" if anything else is chosen.

I'm struggling to add a third thank you page. If user select Y46 then the user is directed to "thank-you-y46" but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I've only been coding a couple months.

Thanks for any help you can give!

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
            $(".btn-submit").click(function() {
                    var manuscript = $('#manuscript_ready__c').val();
                    var country = $('#Country').val();
                    var lpv = ($.inArray(manuscript, ["YPN","Y13"]) > -1 && $.inArray(country, ["USA","CAN"])> -1) ? "thank-you" : "guide-thank-you";
                    var hostURL = window.location.origin;
                    window.module.lp.form.data.url = hostURL +"/" +lpv;
            });
    });
```

Comment: The solution really is to basically never write statements like `($.inArray(manuscript, ["YPN","Y13"]) > -1 && $.inArray(country, ["USA","CAN"])> -1) ? "thank-you" : "guide-thank-you"` - write that in a more expressive, longer, but easier to read, understand and expand manner.

Comment: Keeping the hard-to-read format, you put another `$.inArray ? :` *inside* the `:` part of your existing query.  It will be even harder to read.

Comment: Have you considered [if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
($.inArray(manuscript, ["YPN","Y13"]) > -1 && $.inArray(country, 
["USA","CAN"])> -1) ? "thank-you" : (($.inArray(manuscript, "Y46") > -1 && 
$.inArray(country, ["USA","CAN"]) > -1)  ? "third-page" : "guide-thank-you");
```

Comment: Even *if* this works the code deserves a downvote.

Comment: @luk2302 How else do you suggest they get the result they want using ternary operators?

Comment: By not using the ternary operator.

Comment: There's no requirement in the question to use the ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks all! I really appreciate the feedback, on multiple fronts. I'll try this and also work out a way to do this with IF / ELSE. This in Unbounce and there are a few weird things I have to work through.